# Oracle APEX apex_string.split order by

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Does  apex_string.split   always guarantee that the order of the rows returned is the order of the characters of the string ?
Can I rely on the rownum to always correspond to 1 for the first character of the split string ?
or do I need to add a order by rownum ?

What is the method to get the rows in the same order of the characters of the string ?

My requirement is to insert the rows returned by apex_string.split in the same order as the characters of the string.

I am currently executing the below, will this maintain the character order ?

```
select t.column_value value, rownum seq
  from table(apex_string.split('test','')) t
bulk collect into ins_arr;

for i in ins_arr.first..ins_arr.last
loop

   /* execute insert statement */
   insert into table (seq, value ) 
   values (ins_arr.seq,ins_arr.value);

end loop
```

The insert should result in

| seq | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | t |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | s |
| 4 | t |

Thank you in advance,

Comment: With regard to the actual output of the split function, this should be added to the documentation. The intent is that the APEX_STRING split methods should preserve the original order of the substrings extracted. I'm aware of a number of usages that assume this.

Comment: Side Note: if the query includes a join to another table, the ordering may be lost (`rownum` will no longer necessarily be sequential with regards to the output from the function).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I do intent to join to another table , but the join table will hold only one row and one column. 
 Even in this case, will the rownum not be in the same order as the characters of the string ? 
 For eg. 
 with ename as ( select ename, empno FROM emp /* returns KING */ 
 where empno = 7839 ) 
 select rownum as seq, empno, trim(column_value) ename_char from ename, table(apex_string.split(ename,'')) 
 order by seq

Comment: Yes; but to guarantee the order, make sure to put the table() query in a subquery or CTE on its own, and generate the rownum within it, e.g.:
`select t.value, t.seq, x.* from (
select column_value value, rownum seq from table(apex_string.split('test',''))
) t join other_table x on...`

Comment: BTW, if you don't actually need to query any other table, you can avoid SQL altogether - e.g.: `declare l_strings apex_t_string; begin l_strings := apex_string.split('test',''); for i in 1..l_strings.count loop ... end loop; end;`

Comment: Thank You for your timely help and guidance.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's guaranteed, becuase if it was, it would be in the documentation. But I think you can accomplish what you want by changing your routine. (Note, I have not verified this.)

```
insert into table (seq, value)
select t.column_value value, 
       row_number() over (order by t.column_value)
from table(apex_string.split('test','')) t
```

I think you can do the same with rownum, but I'm never 100% sure what order the `rownum` and the `order by` happen in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but order by t.column_value will order it alphabetically which will put 'e' before t.  I would like to order it in the same order as the characters in the string

Comment: Oh good catch. In that case I think you could use rownum, but that leaves the question of whether the rows will be in the order you expect.